# how to sleep in Qt4

Tags: qt, qt4

I just found it is NOT easy to make a **sleep** call in **Qt4**. I wrote some code in **Qt5** and have few `QThread::msleep()` calls in my `main()` and other places. I want to convert those code to **Qt4** but cannot find an easy way to convert these **msleep** calls.

```
error: C2248: 'QThread::msleep' : cannot access protected member declared in class 'QThread'
```

Somebody suggested subclass the QThread class. Why I need to go that far?  no simple way to just sleep a while?

Comment: if you need `sleep` in 99% of cases it means that you are doing something wrong.

Comment: I know what you are saying. I am doing a prototype. So I need to simulate some use cases which are not function yet. Sleep is useful then.

Comment: see my answer it is much better then mutex concept.

Comment: Be aware when using all kinds of sleep() etc. in the main thread, your UI will block completely. That's something one usually doesn't want.

Answer (score 6):

You can use a wait condition:

```
QWaitCondition wc;
QMutex mutex;
QMutexLocker locker(&mutex);
wc.wait(&mutex, milliseconds);
```

Comment: +1 one from me for creativity. Also somewhat sick, but hey ;)

Answer (score 4):

You can subclass QThread to expose this methods if you insist on sleep:

```
class SleepThread : public QThread {
public: 
   static inline void msleep(unsigned long msecs) { 
       QThread::msleep(msecs);
   }
};
```